# basename or endswith in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using `awk` to get the `pid` of a specific process by name.

```
#!/bin/sh

for pid in $(ps | awk '$4 == "foo" { print $1 }')
do
    i=1
    echo "killing foo at pid $pid"
    kill $pid && echo 'ok' || echo 'failed'
done
```

where `ps` output on OSX is something like:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1858 ttys000    0:00.15 -bash
 4148 ttys000    0:01.37 /a/b/c/foo
```

but my shell script only works if the process in the `CMD` column is exactly `foo` (no absolute paths).

I'm thinking I can use `basename`, but how do I call it from `awk`? 

 **OR** 
Is there something like `$4.endswith('foo')` in `awk`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`awk` can use regular expressions. So rather than `$4 == "foo"`, you could do something like:

```
awk '$4 ~ /\/foo$/ { print $1 }'
```

The regular expression is between the `/` and `/`. `\/foo$` says "a backslash followed by foo and then the end of the field." In this case, your field is `/a/b/c/foo`, so it would match.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to regular expressions, you can use string manipulation as `substr($4, length($4) - 2) == "foo"`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should use a `while read` construct instead of `for`. With a `for` loop, you have to wait for the command in the `$(...)` to execute before the for loop can start. Plus, you *could* overrun the command buffer. Not a major issue today, but when you run into it, you'll never get any indication that something went wrong:

```
ps | awk '$4 == "foo" { print $1 }' | while read pid
do
    i=1
    echo "killing foo at pid $pid"
    kill $pid && echo 'ok' || echo 'failed'
done
```

Nothing much to do with your problem, but I need to get that off my chest.

---

Now on to your Answer:

The `awk` automatically does a loop, so since you're using `awk` anyway, why not let it do the work for you? Most `awk` implementations have a `system` command, so you can execute the `kill` right inside your `awk` script.

Also, take a look at `man ps` and check your PS options. Most ps command take the `-o` option which allows you to specify which fields to print. My `ps` command (which just happens to be on OS X) allows you to use `ucomm` which is just the name of the command without the directory or the command line parameters. Sounds useful for your situation. I'll use `ps -opid, ucomm` which will print only two columns for the `ps` command: The PID, and the command name sans directory and command line parameters:

```
$ ps -o pid,ucomm
  PID UCOMM
    1 launchd         
   10 kextd           
   11 UserEventAgent  
   12 mDNSResponder   
   13 opendirectoryd  
   14 notifyd         
   15 fseventsd       
   16 configd         
   17 diskarbitrationd
   18 syslogd
```

(Just one warning, it looks like `ucomm` cuts things off at the 14th or 16th column. Just to let you know).

For `awk`, we can use the `-v` parameter to define an Awk variable. This is useful in case you write a shell script, and want awk to take the name of the program from the command parameters.

In Awk, as you know, $1 will represent the PID and $2 will represent the command sans the directory or command line parameters.

We can use the `$2 == command` to filter out all the lines in your `ps` command where the command is `foo`. This is a shortcut to the `if` statement.

And, most implementations of `awk` have a `system` function which can be used to run commands like `kill` from inside your `awk` script. Looks like we have almost everything we need:

```
ps -o pid,ucomm | awk -v command="foo" '$2 == command {system("kill " $1)}'
```

That's a nice clean one liner, but it doesn't check the status of the system command, nor does it echo out when it fails or what command and PID you're killing.

Good thing that Awk isn't just an abstruse command. It's also an abstruse programming language. We could test the return of the `system` command and add a few print statements. I didn't test this, but it should be pretty close:

```
ps -o pid,ucomm | awk -v command="foo" '$2 == command {
   print "Killing " $2 " at PID " $1
   if (system("kill " $1)) {
       print "Failed to kill PID " $1
   }
}'
```

The `if` may have to be `if (! system("kill " $1)) {` instead.

Answer (score 2):

For the condition, you can use

```
$4 ~ /\/foo$/
```

which translates to "the 4th field matches an (escaped) forward-slash followed by 'foo' at the end of the line."

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to kill all processes which has name 'foo', how about:

```
killall foo
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking for pids, you must exclude the awk process, otherwise it could kill the search process instead.

```
kill $(ps -aef | awk -v program="mplayer" '$0 ~ program {if ($0 !~ "awk") print $2}')
```